# Scala: List[Tuple3] to Map[String,String]

Tags: list, scala, dictionary, type-conversion, tuples

I've got a query result of `List[(Int,String,Double)]` that I need to convert to a `Map[String,String]` (for display in an html select list)

My hacked solution is:

```
val prices = (dao.getPricing flatMap {
  case(id, label, fee) =>
    Map(id.toString -> (label+" $"+fee))
  }).toMap
```

there must be a better way to achieve the same...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A little more concise:

```
val prices =
  dao.getPricing.map { case (id, label, fee) => ( id.toString, label+" $"+fee)} toMap
```

shorter alternative:

```
val prices =
  dao.getPricing.map { p => ( p._1.toString, p._2+" $"+p._3)} toMap
```

Comment: there you go, nice one, +1, plus a prize, concision is king

Comment: +1 for first alternative, -1 to the second ... giving things names is at *lot* more readable than p._1 etc. (Although virtualeyes might consider making the dao return a Pricing case class rather than using a triple, in which case the second option would be fine).

Comment: I agree, I prefer it, too. Just added for reference.

Comment: @MattR you're right, using ScalaQuery, could just as well return a case class instance, but thought I'd explore tuples (since vast majority of query results are cast to case class instances, quite convenient)

Comment: @MattR I switched to case class instance, the cleanest approach, and minimal extra overhead compared to returning a tuple subset

Comment: @virtualeyes Cool! YMMV, but my personal style rule is to always use  case classes instead of tuples with arity > 2 (with the possible exception when all uses fit within a single editor screen).

Comment: @MattR I have yet to use tuple based query results at all, this question was a failed experiment in that respect as I am back to case class instances ;-) Of course, yes, when querying for a field or 2, tuples make sense. ScalaQuery, btw, completely rocks

Answer (score 9):

How about this?

```
val prices: Map[String, String] =
  dao.getPricing.map {
    case (id, label, fee) => (id.toString -> (label + " $" + fee))
  }(collection.breakOut)
```

The method `collection.breakOut` provides a `CanBuildFrom` instance that ensures that even if you're mapping from a `List`, a `Map` is reconstructed, thanks to the type annotation, and avoids the creation of an intermediary collection.

Comment: +1. odd, what on earth is collection.breakout? ;-) I like that Map has been removed from the map{} block, but now it's been added to the return type ;-(, compiler inference rocks, no like type type type, that's for Java people ;-)

Comment: @virtualeyes Either you write toMap and you have to create an intermediary collection, or you use `breakOut` with the type annotation.

Comment: @Jean-Phillipe ah ok, so my approach is not only poor, but inefficient as well ;-) No big deal here, pricing consists of a handful of records, any which way does the trick, was just looking for a cleaner solution than what I had hacked together