# How to create Map[Int,Set[String]] in scala by reading a CSV file?

Tags: scala, csv

I want to create Map[Int,Set[String]] in scala by reading input from a CSV file.

My file.csv is,

```
sunny,hot,high,FALSE,no
sunny,hot,high,TRUE,no
overcast,hot,high,FALSE,yes
rainy,mild,high,FALSE,yes
rainy,cool,normal,FALSE,yes
rainy,cool,normal,TRUE,no
overcast,cool,normal,TRUE,yes
```

I want the output as,

```
var Attributes = Map[Int,Set[String]] = Map()

Attributes += (0 -> Set("sunny","overcast","rainy"))
Attributes += (1 -> Set("hot","mild","cool"))
Attributes += (2 -> Set("high","normal"))
Attributes += (3 -> Set("false","true"))
Attributes += (4 -> Set("yes","no"))
```

This 0,1,2,3,4 represents the **column number** and Set contains the distinct values in **each column**.

I want to add each (Int -> Set(String)) to my attribute "Attributes". ie, If we print Attributes.size , it displays 5(In this case).

Comment: Look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284423/read-entire-file-in-scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284423/read-entire-file-in-scala) to see how to read the lines into memory. To avoid performance issues consider using `Streams`. `zipWithIndex` will give you the line number with each line. Iterate over the lines and create your `Map`. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one of the [existing answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238134/how-can-i-read-a-csv-file-and-put-its-content-in-a-map-in-scala) to read in the CSV file. You'll have a two dimensional array or vector of strings. Then build your map.

```
// row vectors
val rows = io.Source.fromFile("file.csv").getLines.map(_.split(",")).toVector
// column vectors
val cols = rows.transpose
// convert each vector to a set
val sets = cols.map(_.toSet)
// convert vector of sets to map
val attr = sets.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap).toMap
```

The last line is bit ugly because there is no direct `.toMap` method. You could also write

```
val attr = Vector.tabulate(sets.size)(i => (i, sets(i))).toMap
```

Or you could do the last two steps in one go:

```
val attr = cols.zipWithIndex.map { case (xs, i) => 
  (i, xs.toSet) 
} (collection.breakOut): Map[Int,Set[String]]
```

Comment: If I use another dataset, it show an error, ie, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: transpose requires all collections have the same size