# Reading CSV into Map[String, Array[String]] in Scala

Tags: scala, csv

Given a csv in the format below, what is the best way to load it into Scala as type `Map[String, Array[String]]`, with the first key being the unique values for `Col2`, and the value `Array[String]]` as all co-occurring values of Col1?

```
a,1,
b,2,m
c,2,
d,1,
e,3,m
f,4,
g,2,
h,3,
I,1,
j,2,n
k,2,n
l,1,
m,5,
n,2,
```

I have tried to use the function below, but am getting errors trying to add to the Option type:
`+= is not a member of Option[Array[String]]`

In addition, I get `overloaded method value ++ with alternatives:`
with regards to the line `case None => mapping ++ (linesplit(2) -> Array(linesplit(1)))`

```
def parseCSV() : Map[String, Array[String]] = {
    var mapping = Map[String, Array[String]]()
    val lines = Source.fromFile("test.csv")
    for (line <- lines.getLines) {
      val linesplit = line.split(",")
      mapping.get(linesplit(2)) match {
        case Some(_) => mapping.get(linesplit(2)) += linesplit(1)
        case None => mapping ++ (linesplit(2) -> Array(linesplit(1)))
      }
    }
    mapping
  }
}
```

I am hoping for a `Map[String, Array[String]]` like the following:

```
(2 -> Array["b","c","g","j", "k", "n"])
(3 -> Array["e","h"])
(4 -> Array["f"])
(5 -> Array["m"])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read a CSV file and put its content in a Map in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238134/how-can-i-read-a-csv-file-and-put-its-content-in-a-map-in-scala)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:
First - read the file to List[List[String]]:

```
val rows: List[List[String]] = using(io.Source.fromFile("test.csv")) { source =>
   source.getLines.toList map { line =>
   line.split(",").map(_.trim).toList
  }
}
```

Then, because the input has only 2 values per row, I filter the rows (rows with only one value I want to ignore)

```
val filteredRows = rows.filter(row => row.size > 1)
```

And the last step is to groupBy the first value (which is the second column - the index column is not returned from Source.fromFile):

```
filteredRows.groupBy(row => row.head).mapValues(_.map(_.last)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't complete, but it should give you an outline of how it might be done.

```scala
io.Source
  .fromFile("so.txt")    //open file
  .getLines()            //line by line
  .map(_.split(","))     //split on commas
  .toArray               //load into memory
  .groupMap(_(1))(_(0))  //Scala 2.13

//res0: Map[String,Array[String]] = Map(4 -> Array(f), 5 -> Array(m), 1 -> Array(a, d, I, l), 2 -> Array(b, c, g, j, k, n), 3 -> Array(e, h))
```

You'll notice that the file resource isn't closed, and it doesn't handle malformed input. I leave that for the diligent reader.

Answer (score 1):

For the above code mutable Map & ArrayBuffer should be used, as they could be mutated/updated later.

```
def parseCSV(): Map[String, Array[String]] = {
val mapping = scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, ArrayBuffer[String]]()
val lines = Source.fromFile("test.csv")
for (line <- lines.getLines) {
  val linesplit = line.split(",")
  val key = line.split(",")(1)
  val values = line.replace(s",$key", "").split(",")
  mapping.get(key) match {
    case Some(_) => mapping(linesplit(1)) ++= values
    case None =>
      val ab = ArrayBuffer[String]()
      mapping(linesplit(1)) = ab ++= values
  }
}
 mapping.map(v => (v._1, v._2.toArray)).toMap
}
```